# Why is my cpu maxing out on 1 out of the 4 cores?

Tags: nvidia, gnome, xorg, cpu, 19.04

My problem is that my CPU tends to spike and max out which slows down everything I try to do. The computer I have ran windows 10 perfectly fine (gaming too) so I would expect ubuntu 19.04 to run without many kinks considering it is even lighter weight. But, I am struggling with diagnosing the problem even through searching everyone else's related posts so hopefully some guru out there can save my day. I am a developer and I love the way linux commands work which is why I switched from windows but I was hoping Ubuntu would feel faster rather than bogged down, even on a clean boot.

I have an Acer Aspire E 15 with i5-7200u 2.5Ghz with:

- NVIDIA GeForce 940MX with 2 GB Dedicated VRAM
- 8 GB ram
- 256 GB SSD

One of my four CPU's always spikes to around max. Not sure if this is the cause of the problem but ubuntu 19.04 runs significantly slow. Firefox is slow to respond when opening new tabs or writing text in the search field. Clicking on "show applications" in the bottom left of desktop is also very slow to respond. Just moving my mouse around sometimes maxes out the CPU for Xorg and gnome shell. Here is the output from running `$ top`

`PID USER       PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND`

`1542 evan      20   0 2377540 174804  76628 S  48.8   2.2   0:31.28 gnome-she+ 
 1403 evan      20   0  477176  93928  74108 R  38.9   1.2   0:20.01 Xorg

 2264 evan      20   0  836600  44096  33096 S   2.0   0.5   0:03.23 gnome-ter+ 
 2287 evan      20   0  656968  47776  33788 S   2.0   0.6   0:03.64 gnome-sys+ 
 1577 evan      20   0  295620  26292  17212 S   1.3   0.3   0:00.85 ibus-exte+ 
    1 root      20   0  165020  10208   7544 S   0.7   0.1   0:02.52 systemd

    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.17 kworker/u+ 
   46 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.22 kworker/3+ 
 1566 evan      20   0  392520   8160   6680 S   0.3   0.1   0:00.87 ibus-daem+ 
 1901 evan      20   0 2022172 270444 144136 S   0.3   3.4   0:13.93 firefox

 1998 evan      20   0 1429016 157100 106876 S   0.3   2.0   0:09.97 Web Conte+ 
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd

    3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp

    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp 
    5 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0+ 
    6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0+ 
    8 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu+`

Here is a picture of my system monitor "resources" tab showing that 1 of my four cpus is maxing out.

[System Monitor with CPU1 spiking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoEUT.png)

Comment: You may have a GNOME extension problem. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working fine after I switched Nvidia proprietary driver instead of open source nouveau as shown in the picture and rebooted. Here is a picture of the setting I switched in additional drivers: 
[Additional Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5GGB.png)

And here are my four cpus now:

[Four cpus chillin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4itTy.png)

Thanks for the responses though. Not sure exactly why the open source driver was so much worse at integrating but this works for now :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have installed too many services/daemons  such as rtp streaming which will add unneeded stress on CPU by keeping connections established "is usually my problem" make a condensed list of needed packages such as
Cockpit
Clvm
Lvm2
Ect...